# Creating a container in blob storage Azure - PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

I am following this tutorial, about manipulating blobs:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/

It isn't clear on the following things:

1) How to set up a connection, in the example it uses this line of code:

```
For accessing a live service:

require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder; use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions; use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType; use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

// Create blob REST proxy. $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString)
```

How do I set up the connection string? - what credentials will I need to access blob storage.

Given that I have my Microsoft account details too.

2) How would you create a new storage account

When you log into your portal, a key/account is set up for you. How do you create a new one via php

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In that tutorial you referenced, the connection string format is shown near the top of the article:

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http|https];AccountName=[yourAccount];AccountKey=[yourKey]`

Now you need to create a storage account within the portal. Each storage account has a name (`yourAccount`) and a key (`yourKey`). Once you create a storage account via the portal, you'll see it listed. for instance, I created `dmakhome` for this example:

[image: Storage account created]

Click on its name, which opens the Dashboard view for that storage account:

[image: Storage account dashboard]

At the very bottom of the screen, in the black bottom border, you'll see an icon, **Manage Keys**. Click that, and you'll then see both a primary and a secondary key (you can grab either one):

[image: Storage keys]

Copy the key to the clipboard, and create a $connectionString of the format above, substituting your storage account name and newly-copied key.

Comment: Thanks david. But how would you create a storage container through php without logging into the portal and setting it up that way?

Comment: You only create the storage *account* via the portal (and if you don't want to use the portal, you can use the command-line tools very easily - download either the PowerShell version or the cross-platform version [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/) ). Creating a *container* requires you to create a storage proxy, as your sample code above has, then call createContainer(), which returns an object referencing that container. From that point, you can work with blobs easily within that container.

Comment: And... that example you referenced? Scroll down the page and you'll see a bunch of sample code for creating a container within the storage account, along with various container permissions. It's actually a pretty thorough walkthrough.

Comment: It is complaining the container does not exist, my connection string is as follows:

$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=<name of container>;AccountKey=<primary access key>';

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

use WindowsAzure\Table\Models\Entity;

use WindowsAzure\Table\Models\EdmType;


$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY';

$tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createTableService($connectionString);

//Than try to create table or blob


try {

 $tableRestProxy->createTable('newtasks');

}
catch(ServiceException $e){

  $code = $e->getCode();

  $error_message = $e->getMessage();

  echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";

}
```