# Blob Storage - connection string not working php

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I wrote this:

[Creating a container in blob storage Azure - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282789/creating-a-container-in-blob-storage-azure-php/15285803?noredirect=1#comment21569467_15285803)

The following is my connections sting format:

It is complaining the container does not exist, my connection string is as follows:

`$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=<name of container>;AccountKey=<primary access key>'; –`

However when I connect like this, it keeps complaining that the container cannot be found, and pops a 404 error. When I stick the storage name in name of container and the primary key in key

Any idea why?

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
<?php


require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=<name of container>;AccountKey=<primary access key>'; –`

// Create blob REST proxy.
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);


try {
    // List blobs.
    $blob_list = $blobRestProxy->listBlobs(<container>);
    $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();

    foreach($blobs as $blob)
    {
        echo $blob->getName().": ".$blob->getUrl()."<br />";
    }
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
    // Error codes and messages are here: 
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179439.aspx
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}

?>
```

error:

404: Fail: Code: 404 Value: The specified container does not exist. details (if any): ï»¿ContainerNotFoundThe specified container does not exist. RequestId:44efdbaf-0a20-4b35-96bf-9dcc486ab9a1 Time:2013-03-08T15:00:36.7615754Z.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you're executing to create the container. You cannot read/write from/to a container until it exists.

Comment: I have added it above

Comment: Have you created your container? If you look in the Azure portal is it there (within the storage account click on the containers link)? Sorry to ask what may be a silly question, but in this question you don't show the container creation and in the last question you asked there seems to be some confusion between containers and storage accounts

Comment: Im slightly confused, wont providing the storage account and key give you access to its container?

Comment: No - as David Makongon said in the comments of the linked question, you need to create the container first: $blobRestProxy->createContainer("mycontainer", $createContainerOptions);

Comment: A storage account can have multiple containers within it, and there is not default container created. In the tutorial you linked to you need to run the code under http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/#header-8 at least once to create the container named "mycontainer"

Comment: and which container is the blob stored in? If the containers are created every-time the script is called, will that lead to duplicate containers permanently created

Comment: The blob is stored in the container you reference - in this case the container names "mycontainer". But you never show the part where you create this container, which is why we are trying to confirm that the container exists. In the azure portal, do you see a container named "mycontainer"?

Comment: Thanks guys I never saw the container tab in the storage tab in azure. So I was confused about the difference between the two.  Got it to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure there is a difference between a *Storage Account* and a *container*.

A Storage Account is a collection of containers - theoretically only limited by the storage limit within an Azure account.

In your question you do not appear to be creating the container "mycontainer" within your Storage Account. This would explain the "The specified container does not exist" exception - until you explicitly create a container, it does not exist.

You can check that your container exists from within the Azure Portal - within a Storage Account you will see a link to containers - under that link is a list of all the containers for that Storage Account.

---

If the container is missing, you need to create it - from the tutorial you linked, this line of code needs to be executed at least once:

```
$blobRestProxy->createContainer("mycontainer", $createContainerOptions);
```